# Mysql auto_increment proceed with lowest value

Tags: mysql, sql, auto-increment

My problem is: I have a table with an auto_increment column. When I insert some values, all is right.
Insert first row : ID 1
Insert second row : ID 2

Now I want to insert a row at ID 10.

My problem is, that after this there are only rows inserted after ID 10 (which is the normal behaviour ).

But I want that the database first fills up ID 3-9 before making that.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

To clarify: this is for an URL shortener I want to build for myself.
I convert the id to a word(a-zA-z0-9) for searching, and for saving in the database I convert it to a number which is the ID of the table.

The Problem is now: 
I shorten the first link (without a name) -> ID is 1 and the automatically name is 1 converted to a-zA-Z0-9 which is a

Next the same happenes -> ID is 2 and the name is b, which is 2 converted.

Next interesting, somebody want to name the link `test` -> ID is `4597691` which is the converted `test`

Now if somebody adds another link with no name -> ID is `4597692 which`  would be `tesu` because the number is converted.

I want that new rows will be automatically inserted at the last gap that was made (here 3)

Comment: Why would you want that? What's wrong with ids 3-9 missing?

Comment: I would really like to know why would you face such a condition. This can end up being a really nagging issue, one which has no bearing on the actual data you store (considering these IDs are just internal). Also, see if UUIDs are an alternative you are looking for

Comment: Im trying to make my own link shortener. I convert the id to to the url name and back. If I make a short link with the name JohnDoeJohnDoe  the next who want to have a random name will have JohnDoeJohnDof and thats maybe too long.

Comment: @gluca, this will make your inserts slow, slow down your database with useless tests for missing keys, for no benefit whatsoever. Al that needs to happen is that the id's are unique.  Also you face all sorts of referential issues if you reuse previously used ids. The sequential numbering breaks when MySQL deletes a number. This is a very bad idea.

Comment: @gluca: I fail to see the connection between `1`, `2`, `3`, `10` and `JohnDoeJohnDoe` ...

Comment: @ypercube 1,2,3 and 4597691 - a,b,c and test

Comment: So, you have a link that looks like `http://myweb.com/user/4597691/profile.html` A 32-bit integer can have at most 10 (decimal) digits.

Comment: I have a link like `http://myweb.com/test` then I convert `test` to a number which would be in this case `4597691` and look in my table for a row with the id `4597691`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have another integer column for URL IDs.

Your process then might look like this:

- If a default name is generated for a link, then you simply insert a new row, fill the URL ID column with the auto-increment value, then convert the result to the corresponding name.
- If a custom name is specified for a URL, then, after inserting a row, the URL ID column would be filled with the number obtained from converting the chosen name to an integer.

And so on. When looking up for integer IDs, you would then use the URL ID column, not the table auto-increment column.

If I'm missing something, please let me know.

Comment: That sounds good and I think it has more performance than searching everytime for a free gap, I'll maybe implement this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could do 6 dummy inserts and delete/update them later as you need. The concept of the auto increment, by design, is meant to limit the application's or user's control over the number to ensure a unique value for every single record entered into the table.

Comment: I think that would be not so good if I proceed with 1.2.3 and then something like 1000. But a good idea

Comment: The suggestion is not good but only because the request is not good. +1 for making the point that auto-generated are IDs are there to provide **uniqueness** and not **absense of gaps**.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE AUTO_INCREMENT = 3;
```

Comment: Thank you, but if I insert values into my DB (this is by a php page) I want that they are automatically set in the 3rd row. I think I cant get the id every time I set a row and add 1 and save it, to use it later (I think thats not very pretty).

Answer (score 0):

You would have to find first unused id, store it as user variable, use as id for insert.

```
SELECT @id := t1.id +1 
FROM sometable t1 LEFT JOIN sometable t2 
ON t2.id = t1.id +1 WHERE t2.id IS NULL LIMIT 1;

INSERT INTO sometable(id, col1, col2, ... ) VALUES(@id, 'aaa', 'bbb', ... );
```

You will have to run both queries for every insert if you still have gaps, its up to you to decide whether it is worth doing it.

Comment: That sounds good, but **select table.id from table where id is null limit 1** returns an empty result

Comment: @gluca, **that's not** the query in piotrm's answer, what are you talking about?

Comment: @Johan ok, whats the query then? you get the t1.id where t2.id is null and get only one result. I have only modified it that it works for one table i havent spoken of more. Can you please say how your sql is working (dont understand the start of the third line)?

Comment: @gluca: There is exactly 1 table in this answer: `sometable`.

Comment: @ypercube: Ah now I see, but why there is a `LEFT JOIN` thought(that made me guess that sorry). This is for combining two tables, isnt it?

Comment: Yes, but in this case, it combines the table to itself so it can find the first gap.

Comment: For what stands sometable t1 and sometable t2. Are t1 and t2 aliases?

Answer (score 0):

not 100% sure what you're trying to achieve but something like this might work:

```
drop table if exists foo;
create table foo
(
id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
row_id tinyint unsigned unique not null default 0
)
engine=innodb;

insert into foo (row_id) values (1),(2),(10),(3),(7),(5);

select * from foo order by row_id;

+----+--------+
| id | row_id |
+----+--------+
|  1 |      1 |
|  2 |      2 |
|  4 |      3 |
|  6 |      5 |
|  5 |      7 |
|  3 |     10 |
+----+--------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: thank you, but I mean,(regarding to your example) if I now insert: insert into foo (id,row_id) values (10,11) and then insert: insert into foo (row_id) values (12) then the id of the row with the row_id 12 should be 7 and not 11. Hope I have explained it right